# Date formatting yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date in yyyymmdd format to yyyy-mm-dd with the following code:

```
tdrDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyymmdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This works the only problem is that when I have a date such as this "**20070205**" I get back "**2007-01-05**".  I don't know why this is happening, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
tdrDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You need MM, not mm. mm is for minutes.

Answer (score 11):

It should be:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Capital 'MM' in the first date format string.

Comment: Wow, there were a lot of close ones here!

Answer (score 3):

`"yyyymmdd"` must be `"yyyyMMdd"`.

**mm** is for **minutes**.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
tdrDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

use MM instead mm,
mm is for minute &
MM is for Month that is why it is taking 01 (default value of MM).

Answer (score 2):

The format string is case-sensitive, so "mm" is different to "MM". You are parsing *minutes* ("mm"), which is why the value of months ("MM") is always at the default value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
DateTime.ParseExact("20070205", "yyyyMMdd", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** I know nothing about C#'s date formatting.

But I'm guessing the problem is that you used `mm` in the first format string, and `MM` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

A handy reference: [SteveX Compiled: String formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you're parsing the date to create a date object, formatting the date object to a string, and discarding the date object. That sounds like more work than simple string processing:

```
tdrDate = dateString.Substring(0,4) + '-' + 
    dateString.Substring(4,2) + '-' + 
    dateString.Substring(6,2);
```

If you're targeting .Net 5 or later, you can use string interpolation:

```
tdrDate = $"{dateString.Substring(0,4)}-{dateString.Substring(4,2)}-{dateString.Substring(6,2)}";
```

That line is a bit long. If you're targeting .Net 7 or later, maybe:

```
tdrDate = $"{
    dateString.Substring(0,4)
}-{
    dateString.Substring(4,2)
}-{
    dateString.Substring(6,2)
}";
```

I'll admit I've not found a way to split long interpolated strings across lines that I really like.

Unless you need the validation that's performed by `DateTime.ParseExact()`, which will throw a `System.FormatException` if given an invalid date, I'd probably just use the string formatting approach.

Comment: This allocates a new temporary string for every substring operation *and* can easily result in errors or invalid dates. Nothing guarantees that the input string is in YYYYMMDD format. PS: String interpolation wasn't added in .NET 5 either. To avoid the string allocations you'd have to use a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`

Comment: In .NET 6, the oldest supported .NET Core version at this moment, you can store a string in a ReadOnlySpan<char> variable and use either Slice or a range operator, eg `ReadOnlySpan<char> dtSpan=dateString; var year=dt.Slice(0,4);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Nice.