# Date convertion To yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);

The value in txtStartDate.Text is like 31-07-2012

I need to get it as 2012-07-31.

For processing in storedprocedure.

My code is like :

```
            cmd = new SqlCommand("DownloadtoXLSheet", conn);



            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text.ToString();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt1);
```

help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting any string to string "yyyy/MM/dd"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806967/formatting-any-string-to-string-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Or of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4250745/869912).

Answer (score 3):

First off, you don't need the date in a particular format for processing in the stored procedure/database. Once a DateTime has been added as a parameter (of type DateTime), the SQL provider will make sure the SQL server can handle the date.

On the other hand, you might need the date in a particular format for DateTime.Parse to work.

Try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But, maybe you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead, to avoid exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` method instead of `DateTime.Parse`.

```
DateTime result=DateTime.ParseExact("31-07-2012", "dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
DateTime dt = ...;

dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .ToString() method you can specify a format string
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

```
DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```